# Branch Deep Link does not open play store

Tags: android, kotlin, branch.io

I use Branch deep link in my android app with kotlin, I use the following link  https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <application
                android:name="net.app.activity.application"
                android:allowBackup="false"
                android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:supportsRtl="false"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup,android:appComponentFactory">
            <activity android:name="net.app.activity.splash.SplashActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <data android:scheme="app" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                </intent-filter>
                <!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent

.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="app.test-app.link" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="app-alternate.test-app.link" />
                </intent-filter>
    
            </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
                android:value="key...." />
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
                android:value="key...." />
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
 android:value="false" />
```

I add Branch to My ApplicationClass.java :

// Branch logging for debugging
Branch.enableLogging();

```
// Branch object initialization
Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
```

I add Branch to my lancherActivity which is SplashActivity.kt as follows :

```
  override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Branch init
        Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(branchListener).withData(this.intent?.data).init()

    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        this.intent = intent
        // Branch reinit (in case Activity is already in foreground when Branch link is clicked)
        Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback(branchListener).reInit()
    }

    object branchListener : Branch.BranchReferralInitListener {
        override fun onInitFinished(referringParams: JSONObject?, error: BranchError?) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("BRANCH SDK", referringParams.toString())
                // Retrieve deeplink keys from 'referringParams' and evaluate the values to determine where to route the user
                // Check '+clicked_branch_link' before deciding whether to use your Branch routing logic
            } else {
                Log.e("BRANCH SDK", error.message)
            }
        }

    }
```

In my app,In one of my UI, A product with all details like name, quantity, price etc...I want to share this product, I create a share button, When I click on I choose "copied to press...",I copied the Url, then I paste it in the navigator, I want that the app will be opened in the app store But I didn't get this result.
Here's my code of sharing :

```
shareMerchant.setOnClickListener {
            val image = merchant!!.logo
            val url = this.getString(R.string.image_URL) + image
            buo = Utility(this).prepareSharingLink(
                merchant!!.id.toString(),
                "store",
                url,
                UtilityTools.getInstance().getValue(merchant!!.name)
            )
            val lp = LinkProperties()

            val message =
              "Check out this store on App"


            val ss = ShareSheetStyle(this, "Check this out!", message)
                .setCopyUrlStyle(
                    resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send, this.theme),
                    "Copy",
                    "Added to clipboard"
                )
                .setMoreOptionStyle(
                    resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search, this.theme),
                    "Show more"
                )
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.EMAIL)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.MESSAGE)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.HANGOUT)
                .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                .setSharingTitle("Share With")

            buo.showShareSheet(this, lp, ss, object : Branch.BranchLinkShareListener {
                override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
                override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
                override fun onLinkShareResponse(
                    sharedLink: String?,
                    sharedChannel: String?,
                    error: BranchError?
                ) {
                    val metaData: java.util.HashMap<String, String> = java.util.HashMap()
                    if (error == null) {
                        metaData[Defines.Jsonkey.SharedLink.key] = sharedLink!!
                    } else {
                        metaData[Defines.Jsonkey.ShareError.key] = error.message
                    }
                }

                override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {}
            })
```

prepareSharingLink code as follows :

```
fun prepareSharingLink(
        itemID: String,
        itemType: String,
        imageURL: String?,
        customTitle: String = ""
    ): BranchUniversalObject {

        val canonical = itemType.plus("/").plus(itemID)
        val branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject()
        branchUniversalObject.canonicalIdentifier = canonical
        branchUniversalObject.title = customTitle
        branchUniversalObject.setContentDescription("")
        branchUniversalObject.setContentImageUrl(imageURL!!)
        branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemType"] = itemType
        branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemID"] = itemID
        branchUniversalObject.isLocallyIndexable
        branchUniversalObject.isPublicallyIndexable
        branchUniversalObject.setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PRIVATE)
        return branchUniversalObject
    }
```

I want to know if I have an error or something missing in my code? And Why Branch Deep Link does not open with play store?

Comment: Can you share the link with which you are testing this?

Comment: I got the Url, but the problem when I put it in navigator, it does not direct me to play store

Comment: @KartikShandilya I would like to ask u If there's something missing in my code ?

Comment: To check for your setup could you share the link which you got from the SDK?

Comment: Please validate your integration following this - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-testing#section-test-your-branch-integration

Comment: ** ERROR ** : Incorrect package name in Branch dashboard. Please correct your package name in dashboard -> link Settings page. I got this error

Comment: Can you share your app link domain? So that we can review your setup

Comment: I got the following result, but still not work:  ...3. Verifying application package name Passed..
    4. Checking Android Manifest for URI based deep link config ... Passed
    5. Verifying URI based deep link config with Branch dash board. ...  Passed
    6. Verifying intent for receiving URI scheme. ... Passed
    7. Checking AndroidManifest for AppLink config. ... 
    Passed
    8. Verifying any supported custom link domains. ... 
    Passed
    9. Verifying default link domains integrations. ... 
    Passed
    10. Verifying alternate link domains integrations. ...  Passed